# TableView: content hidden on rows that are not screen visible (android)

Tags: android, tableview, appcelerator, hidden, appcelerator-titanium

I've a calendar widget, that is a TableView rotated -90 degrees, after set the TableView data, I add a View rotated 90 degrees the TableViewRows, and set to those Views the new height and width.

On 'scrollend' event, if this reach the TableView limits, at the end of the TableView I push another 20 rows to the end of the TableView data, and at the beginning I unshift 20 rows to the beginning of the TableView data.

This works perfectly on iOS, but on android there is a issue that I can't understand why: all the screen visible TableViewRows are fine (5), but when I scroll to the other TableViewRows it's children are hidden until a 'click' event on the TableView.

Test Project: [test.cal.zip](https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/attachment/58267/test.cal.zip)

JIRA Ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-631

- Start of the TableView (with 20 rows):

[image: Start of the View (with 20 rows)]

- Scrolled a little bit to see the next rows (starting on nº6):

[image: Scrolled a little bit to see the next rows (starting on nº6)]

- After a click on TableView:

[image]

Comment: May I compliment you on this innovative use of transform to create a vertical TableView? Never thought of that. Awesome! I might do a blog post on that at the Appcelerator Blog.

Comment: I think that are some bugs on this, most of this caused by the rotate function, I had to add the content after the rotation, but it was my best approach of doing this in order do to that slider calendar, with a ScrollView it was a little bit slower and more difficult to add views at the beginning of a the ScrollView (I had to manage all children views with left position and use a lot of for loops)

Answer (score 0):

This might well be this bug:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-5862

What do you think?

Comment: If you think it's not, then please create a new JIRA ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Thats not the issue, I had this old post in community: [https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/4304/horizontal-scrollable-calendar-widget-module](https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/4304/horizontal-scrollable-calendar-widget-module). 

I will create a JIRA ticket with an exemple.

Comment: Created a JIRA Ticket for this: [https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-631](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-631), test project added to the main question.