# ScrollView inside TableViewRow don't detect touchEvent or click listener

Tags: touch, tableview, scrollview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've a calendar Widget that's a TableView rotated 90 degrees with a container View inside TableViewRows rotated -90 degrees, and a ScrollView inside the the container View.

This ScrollView doesn't detect the click listener event, but if I change it to a View does, but I have a list of items that I can't put in a simple View.

Any workarounds or advices?

Stackoverflow post with prints and ZIP file: [TableView: content hidden on rows that are not screen visible (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433035/tableview-content-hidden-on-rows-that-are-not-screen-visible-android)

JIRA ticket that has a ZIP with this widget: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-631

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a JIRA related to this functionality [TIMOB-13580](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-13580)

As a workaround you can use **singletap** event.

Hope this will help you