# card previews with scrollableView in titanium alloy app

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I want to implement a scrollable list of cards in my alloy app with previews of previous and next cards. I have researched different properties of scrollView and scrollableView but not able to achieve the previews of previous and next cards. Is it possible to achieve this with scrollView or scrollableView?

Currently, I am achieving this with a horizontal layout of views and addressing the movement with touch events. But the touch events are not as smooth as navigation with scrollableViews.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could achieve the result with a TableView, I've a calendar widget based on a TableView, but here is a bug in android: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20476 but this only happens because I'm rotating 90 degrees the container view, and -90 the content inside the TableViewRows.

Check out this link, you can download my sample and check if fits to you: [TableView: content hidden on rows that are not screen visible (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433035/tableview-content-hidden-on-rows-that-are-not-screen-visible-android)

Comment: I will try your implementation, thanks! One thing though, is it possible to control the scroll distance in TableView, because I can't determine the x and y coordinates on scroll event (tested on Android)? I want to show one card at a time, that means a swipe should only result in scroll amount equal to card dimension.

Comment: You can detect x and y coordinates at the scrollend event, at the scroll event you i think you can achieve the positions by contentOffset.x and contentOffset.y on iOS and on android with totalItemCount, firstVisibleItem and visibleItemCount. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-event-scroll